# Using custom smart pointers in boost python

Tags: c++, python, boost, smart-pointers, boost-python

***I would like to expose objects wrapped in custom smart pointers in python using Boost::Python***

The caveats

- existing usage of the custom smart pointer is too pervasive to
  economically upgrade to the boost smart pointers
- i would like to use the automatic dereferencing technique as described in several locations

The problem is that I cannot seem to get it quite right. Here's a sample code:

**LegacyCode::Ptr** -> legacy smart pointer code

**LegacyCode::Session** -> legacy object that's wrapped in the legacy smart pointer

```
namespace boost { namespace python
{
    template <class T> T* get_pointer(LegacyCode::Ptr<T> const& p)
    {
        return p.get();
    }


    template <typename T>
    struct pointee<LegacyCode::Ptr<T> >
    {
        typedef T type;
    };

}}*

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pyro)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<LegacyCode::Session,LegacyCode::Ptr<LegacyCode::Session>>("Session")
                                          .def("get_type",&LegacyCode::Session::getType);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fully working example. You almost had it - you have to remove the `get_pointer()` from the `boost::python` namespace.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// dummy smart ptr class
template <typename T> class Ptr {
  public:
    typedef T element_type;

    Ptr(): px(0) {}
    Ptr(T* p): px(p) {}

    // base operators
    T* operator->() { return px; }
    const T* operator->() const { return px; }
    T& operator*() { return *px; }
    const T& operator*() const { return *px; }

    // getters
    T* get() { return px; }
    const T* get() const { return px; }

  private:
    T* px;
};

// a dummy class that will be held by your custom smart pointer
class  Session {
  public:
    Session(int value) : value_(value) {}
    virtual ~Session() {}

    // a few methods to play with the class
    int value() const { return value_; };
    void value(int value) { value_ = value; }

  private:
    int value_;
};

// this emulates methods actually using your smart pointers
void print_value_1(const Ptr<Session>& s) {
  std::cout << "[by const reference] The value of this session is " << s->value() << std::endl;
}

void print_value_2(Ptr<Session> s) {
  std::cout << "[by value] The value of this session is " << s->value() << std::endl;
}

// here comes the magic
template <typename T> T* get_pointer(Ptr<T> const& p) {
  //notice the const_cast<> at this point
  //for some unknown reason, bp likes to have it like that
  return const_cast<T*>(p.get());
}

// some boost.python plumbing is required as you already know
namespace boost { namespace python {

  template <typename T> struct pointee<Ptr<T> > {
    typedef T type;
  };

} }

// now the module
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<Session, Ptr<Session>, boost::noncopyable>("Session", init<int>());
  def("print_value_1", &print_value_1);
  def("print_value_2", &print_value_2);
}
```

You can test this with the following python code:

```
import example
s = example.Session(27)
example.print_value_1(s)
example.print_value_2(s)
```

We demonstrate with the example that `boost.python` will correctly run the conversion as required.

Comment: To answer the unknown reason, the `const_cast` is required as a result of `Ptr`'s definition, not because of Boost.Python.  `Ptr` is applying `const` to its element when the `Ptr` itself is `const`.  It is equivalent to the difference between const-pointer and pointer-to-const.  For example, `shared_ptr` makes this distinction in the type itself: `const shared_ptr<T>`  and `shared_ptr<const T>`.

Comment: I currently have the following problem: The CGAL libary has a class that basically wraps a Pointer (called Handle). I want to expose it as if it was a regular whatever-the-handle points to. But unfortunately the Handle doesn't have a element_type variable and therefore I always get compile errors. Any hints?